# Keychain has wrong Gmail Password. Apple Mail Is Still Working But I Can't Find the Password to Log in the Webmail Interface

Tags: mail.app, password, keychain, gmail

Somehow I think I overwrote my password in the keychain with the wrong password for my Gmail account. Somehow Apple Mail is still allowing me to access my account. I still need this Gmail password for other apps besides mail. Is there any way I can recover the password Apple Mail is using?

I have looked at all the questions AskDifferent suggested and tried many searches. I can use the terminal and terminal programs. But I cannot find the correct password in the keychain. Apple Mail must have the correct password somehow if I can still get my email on my machine.

I have searched everywhere in ~/Library/Mail and see no password information.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely Apple Mail uses an access token and not directly the password (especially if you use 2FA for your Google account). To recover the Gmail password, use the account recovery process provided by Google.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Recovery is not possible as the recovery information is a with a phone number that no longer is in service. 2FA is not enabled. I see a whole lot of "application" passwords in keychain but only one, incorrect "account" password (it used to have the correct password but now it has something Apple suggested but that was never set).