# How to access email password not saved in keychain?

Tags: mail.app, email, password

Is there any way to access the password for an email address that is stored in Mac's Mail app but that is not saved in Keychain?

(Both Passwords and Keychain Access seem not to have saved this password. I can see the length of the password in the Mail's preferences and in Internet Accounts but cannot access the password there.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mail doesn’t store passwords.  It saves session states (probably in a token of some kind) so that authentication doesn’t have to keep taking place

Comment: Same as this question.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/458808

Comment: Thanks that's great to know!